# wordpress wpdb result is zero

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have this code for getting order items but the result count is zero!

```
global $wpdb;
$orderitems = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_woocommerce_order_items WHERE order_id = '".$order_id."'");
```

Comment: What do `var_dump($order_id);` and `var_dump($orderitems);` return?

Comment: Also, your code is potentially open to [SQL injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection) attacks as it currently is. Consider using the [prepare()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/) method with your query.

Answer (score 0):

Could be handy to use the following statement for queries. 
In case with multisites or just not to know what database prefix is given.

If table is and record ID exists then result can not be clear.

```
global $wpdb;
$orderitems = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."woocommerce_order_items WHERE order_id = '".$order_id."'");
```

Note: the

```
".$wpdb->prefix."
```